# How do I filter on a gremlin groupCount result?

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server

Below is my Gremlin query running on Tinkerpop. I need to further filter out any color that has a count < 3. How do I refine my query to do this?:

Thanks!

```
` g.V().
    group().
    by("co_ordinate").
    by(outE().
        group(). 
        by("direction").
        by(inV().out().groupCount().
        by("color")))`
```

This returns the following results:

```
`[
   0:
    {
     "10":{
        "East":
            {
              "blue":3,
              "yellow":1
            }
    }
]`
```

Comment: I added an answer below. If you are able to update the question with the Gremlin steps to build a small sample graph that would enable providing tested answers.

Answer (score 0):

You really have two options, filter while creating the group or filter after created. If the group is of a modest size, filtering after it is created will look something like:

```
 select("10").
 select("East").
 unfold().
 where(select(values).is(gt(3)))
```

You can use a similar `where` step to filter while creating the group.

While creating the group, using the air-routes data set as an example, you could filter something like this:

```java
g.V().hasLabel('airport').limit(10).
      group().
        by('code').
        by(out().count()).
        unfold().
        where(select(values).is(gt(10)))
```

which, for the 10 airports picked,  only returns the 5 airports with more than 10 routes (analogous to your colors example):

```
1   {'ASE': 11}
2   {'YLW': 12}
3   {'TYN': 47}
4   {'GEG': 17}
5   {'BLI': 13}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kelvin. The only point I have is that I do not Know "10" or "East" in advance. P.S> : I am reading your book right now and really enjoying it. Thanks so much for publishing it!

Comment: I updated the answer to show an example of filtering the group as it is created